# Partiel differentiating of function inside function

Tags: functions, derivatives

The title probably doesnt make alot of sense, but was the best i could think of.

Say we have a function $f(x,y)=g(3x-2y)$, where g is a differentiable function of 1 variable.

How would i go about partially differentiating f, with respect to x, or with respect to y?

Comment: use the chain rule treating the other variable as a constant

Comment: If i want to find $f_x(x,y)$ then, how exactly would i do it, sorry.
Would i just do as a  normal partial differentiation, so the answer becomes $3g'(3x-2y)$? Or could you show me a bit more directly?

Comment: what you've said is correct yeah. You can try doing $f_y$ too just to double check if you want